# Break grouped values on a pipe (rows) into intervals (cols) in R

Tags: r, pipe, histogram, intervals, group

I have a large dataset of heartrate measurements for 50+ individual's IDs.
(I will use iris dataset as example dataset)

While inspecting data, I needed to summarize this single datatype into multiple columns.
I firstly, managed to do that for quantiles with the help of this site as follows in next chunks.

Then the question is how can I split the data similarly into multiple intervals, defined by the same data, and apply a function to it like 'length'.

The result would be a numerical representation of histogram's data which is more compact as a table than as a graph for 50+ individuals.

```
db$heartrate_seconds %>% 
  group_by( session_id ) %>% 
  summarise( as_tibble( rbind( summary( heartrate ) ) ) )
```

```
db$heartrate_seconds %>% 
  group_by( session_id ) %>% 
  summarise( as_tibble( rbind( fivenum( heartrate ) ) ) )
```

```
iris %>% 
  group_by( Species ) %>% 
  summarise( 
    quantile( Sepal.Length, c(0, 0.01, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.99, 1), 
              type=5, na.rm=TRUE) %>% rbind %>% as_tibble,
    Range = `99%`-`1%`,
    Mean = mean(Sepal.Length) %>% floor
    ) %>% 
  print.data.frame( right = FALSE)
```

This lastone produces:

```
  Species    0%  1%  25% 50% 75% 99% 100% Range Mean
1 setosa     4.3 4.3 4.8 5.0 5.2 5.8 5.8  1.5   5   
2 versicolor 4.9 4.9 5.6 5.9 6.3 7.0 7.0  2.1   5   
3 virginica  4.9 4.9 6.2 6.5 6.9 7.9 7.9  3.0   6
```

The desired result of the interval's summary would be like this in %

```
     Species  N (4.3,5.02] (5.02,5.74] (5.74,6.46] (6.46,7.18] (7.18,7.9]
1     setosa 50         54          42           2           0          0
2 versicolor 50          6          36          40          18          0
3  virginica 50          2           4          42          30         22
```

Answer (score 0):

I came to this solution by using split with seq, which allows to set the number of intervals and avoid to hardcode them.

I am open to suggestions of alternate methods that could improve readability or performance.

```
s = seq( min(iris$Sepal.Length), 
         max(iris$Sepal.Length), 
         length.out = 5+1 )

iris %>% 
  group_by( Species ) %>% 
  summarise( 
      N = n(),
      Sepal.Length %>% 
          split( ., cut(., s, right=TRUE)) %>% 
            sapply( function(x) length(x)/N*100 )  %>%
            rbind %>% as_tibble
    ) %>% 
  print.data.frame( right = TRUE)
```

Producing:

```
     Species  N (4.3,5.02] (5.02,5.74] (5.74,6.46] (6.46,7.18] (7.18,7.9]
1     setosa 50         54          42           2           0          0
2 versicolor 50          6          36          40          18          0
3  virginica 50          2           4          42          30         22
```